# Finding Shadow Objects

Tags: java, json, algorithm, jsp

I have a JSON type object like this:

```
{"apple":{"color":"red",shape:"round"},
 "orange":{"color":"orange",shape:"round"},
 "banana":{"color":"yellow","shape":"rectngle"},
 "tomato":{"color":"red",shape:"round"}}
```

My controller returns me this object and in my JSP I want to find out  the shadow objects(shadow fruits in above example)

**Shadow objects**: objects with same properties(e.g. in above example tomato and apple have both properties same, so , they are shadow objects)

**NOTE** the number of properties(color and shape in above example) may vary for various types of objects.. for fruits it is 2-color and shape , if user queries for say , toys , it may have 3 or more properties like: color, price , material

How should I find out the shadow  objects.

Comment: parse this json in scriplets in your jsp, or it would be best to parse this using javascript and then fill the values in your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN my opinion your controller should return JSON with grouped shodow objects. 
JSP should only render result.